# What does this statement about implementing forwarding methods of components mean?

Tags: java, object-oriented, methods, composition

I can't wrap my head around this statement [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Drawbacks):

> One common drawback of using composition instead of inheritance is
>   that methods being provided by individual components may have to be
>   implemented in the derived type, even if they are only forwarding
>   methods

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

When you use inheritance, the class `Derived` will inherit the methods of the `Base` class.  You can use them as they are. You'll override inherited methods only if you need a different behavior,  or if the base method is abstract.

```
public class Base {
   public void presentYourself() { ... }
}
public class Derived extends Base {
}
...
    Derived d = ...; 
    d.presentYourself();    // <<---- works out of the box
```

In the composition, especially if you use composition over inheritance,  you expose in a `Composite` the methods offered by its `Component`.  In absence of inheritance, you will need to implement all the relevant methods of `Component`'s interface in `Composite`. This means that even if you provide exactly the same method than in `Component` and there is no specific behavor,  you'll nevertheless need to implement at least a method that calls the method of the composed `Component` object.

```
public class Component {
   public void presentYourself() { ... }
}
public class Composite {
   private Component c;  
   public void presentYourself() { c.presentYourself(); } //<- FORWARDING
   ...
}
...
    Composite x = ...; 
    x.presentYourself();    // Works only if explicitly implemented
```

In other words, this means that with composition you might have a lot of boilerplate code that just calls a methods of another object, with the same parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It means that, if you're using inheritance, you get the use of the base class's methods for free, whereas if you're using composition, it sometimes takes a little more work to wire up the necessary methods in the classes you're composing.